# Arduino Uno not recognized by Windows 10

Tags: windows, arduino, arduino-uno

I have an Arduino Uno that will not - no matter what I've tried - get recognized by my computer.

I'm running Windows 10 Home on a 64-bit Dell Inspiron laptop.

Have installed arduino software and drivers via official executable on Arduino website. Proper .inf file is sitting in Arduino/drivers directory.

Expected behavior is to plug in Arduino via USB, go to Device Manager, and find Arduino in Ports section or possibly Other Devices section.

There is no Ports or Other Devices section. But there is an

"Unknown USB Device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)"

line in the Universal Serial Bus controllers section. This is the Arduino, as when I unplug the Uno, this device disappears from the USB controllers section.

(By the way, when I plug in the Arduino, I get a notfication that says the recently plugged in device has malfunctioned and Windows does not recognize it.)

Right clicking and going to properties for the Unknown Device, reveals a status of: Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems. (Code 43)
A request for the USB device descriptor failed.

Attempting to update the driver by pointing it directly to the proper directory gives a message that it already has the most up to date driver. However, going to Driver Details in Device Manager says: No driver files are required or have been loaded for this device.

I have disabled Driver Signature Verification already. Still no joy.

I've updated Windows. I've tried to make sure all other USB related drivers are updated. Windows at least says they are when I attempt an update.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Is that a genuine arduino or some arduino clone? if its a cloned arduino, they might use a diferent chip for the usb - serial. You might have to install the right driver for that cloned arduino..

Comment: Thanks @MoGun for contributing. I forgot this was still live. The arduino is not a clone. I called the people I bought it from and they sent out a new one. Worked just fine. Turns out there was something faulty with the first unit.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on the arduino stack exchange site

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the unit was faulty. Place I bought it from sent a new one out and it worked - plug and play, no problems. I'd say if you're in a similar position and have tried everything, contact the supplier and request a new one.

Answer (score 5):

I just had the same problem a while ago, but it was solved when I replaced the USB cord that I first used. For anybody out there who will have the same problem, try considering this. :)

Answer (score 0):

The Arduinos that use the 32U4 chip sometimes are not recognized and appear bricked.  I have had Leonardos and Pro Micros that give errors when plugged into a USB port on Windows 10.  The fix that works for me is to use the boot loader by pressing the reset twice and immediately uploading any sketch.  On the Pro Micro this means using a wire connecting the reset pin to gnd and tapping twice.   You may need to start an upload then hit the rest pin twice to activate the bootloader and get the timing right.  It may take several tries.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with this issue and I was able to [solve] it by using the Windows 10 Arduino IDE editor (not the web create), load one of the Basic sketches such as Blink, compile the sketch for my board Leonardo, plugging in the Arduino Leonardo into the USB port, which displayed the error message "usb device not recognized", and then

- Press Control-U on the keyboard to start the upload. (even though the board is not recognised in the IDE and the port is not found in Tools > Ports)
- Quickly double press the reset button on the Leonardo;
- The Windows 10 computer will make the sound about the USB port being disconnected, and then reconnected. The Arduino will flash various LEDs, and then the simple Blink sketch will load.

Eventually I got it to work after numerous tries. I tried various orders, but the order of steps above is the one that worked. (This process worked on my 2 boards that had the exact same issue!)

I had used the advice from other forums of trying different USB ports, different USB cables, rebooting, reinstalling, that all failed. I ended up buying a new board, and it worked initially, but after downloading my code to the board, it also ended in the same fate. Hence, I think my code (which uses timers) caused the Leonardo to crash and unable to be recognised by Windows 10.  I wasted 6 hours on this problem!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was a miswired BMP280 issue (had put the SCL and SDA wires into the same hole on the breadboard). Using a very  basic sketch such as Blink it was relatively easy to upload and get Windows to recognize the Arduino Nano by pressing the reset button twice while uploading. Why the wiring issue caused a problem I've no idea